# Grouping query fields from different tables (Entity Framework and ASP.NET Core)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to translate this query to entity framework, but it's not working. Can anyone understand why?

```
SELECT
    T3.COD1, T1.COD2,
    COUNT(T1.X1) R1 ,
    ROUND(SUM(T1.X2) / SUM(T2.X3),2) R2,
FROM 
    table1 A, table2 T2, table3 T3 
WHERE 
    T1.O_KEY = T3.O_KEY 
    AND T1.M_KEY = T2.M_KEY 
GROUP BY 
    T3.COD1, T1.COD2 
ORDER BY 
    T3.COD1, T1.COD2
```

Where the (`WHERE T1.O_KEY = T3.O_KEY and T1.M_KEY = T2.M_KE`) instruction is equivalent to `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    T3.COD1, T1.COD2,
    COUNT(T1.X1) R1 ,
    ROUND(SUM(T1.X2) / SUM(T2.X3),2) R2,
FROM 
    table1 A
INNER JOIN 
    table3 T3 ON T1.O_KEY = T3.O_KEY
INNER JOIN 
    table2 T2 ON T1.M_KEY = T2.M_KEY 
GROUP BY 
    T3.COD1, T1.COD2 
ORDER BY 
    T3.COD1, T1.COD2
```

The conversion:

```
//{Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1[App.Models.T1Model]}
var T1 =  _repositoryT1.GetAll(); // return context.T1
var T2 =  _repositoryT2.GetAll(); // return context.T2
var T3 =  _repositoryT3.GetAll(); // return context.T3
```

//Note: The GetAll method does not return results to memory. Operates on Dbset/LINK.T1, T2 and T3 are database tables. The context class is an integral part of Entity Framework. An instance of DbContext represents a session with the database which can be used to query and save instances of entities to a database

```
var query = 
(from xT1 in T1
 join xT3 in T3 on new { k1 = (long)xT1.O_KEY } equals new { k1 = (long)xT3.O_KEY }
 join xT2 in T2 on new { k1 = (long)xT1.M_KEY } equals new { k1 = (long)T2.M_KEY}
 group new { xT3, xT1 } by new { xT3.COD1 , xT1.COD2, xT1, xT3, xT2 } into G
 select new ResultDTO
 {
  COD1 = G.Key.COD1,
  COD2 = G.Key.COD2,
  R1 = T1.Count(),
  R2 = T1.Sum(x => (long)x.X2) / T2.Sum(x => (long)x.X2),
});
```

Comment: EF Core deals with entities, not tables. LINQ isn't a SQL replacement, it's a query language that's translated by EF Core to SQL. The whole point of using EF Core is to let *it* write the JOINs based on relations between your *entities*, not tables. Otherwise just write the SQL query and map the results to an object using eg Dapper.

Comment: Thanks @Panagiotis Kanavos. This query is not very complex shouldn't it be possible to convert?

Comment: BTW that join style in SQL went out of fashion almost 30 years ago, replaced by `JOIN`. It's hard to understand what it does in the first place, and names like `T1` don't help. Is `T1` the main table and T2, T3 related ones? If you rewrite the query using JOINs, the LINQ query will be similar. There's no T2 field in the SQL query, so there shouldn't be any T2 field in the LINQ query either. Casts aren't needed, in fact they'll either result in errors or result in inefficient queries.

Comment: `shouldn't it be possible to convert?` yes, by removing all of it. If you use EF Core properly you can remove all this code. `dbContext.Orders.GroupBy(o=>o.Category.Name).Select(g=>new {Category=g.Key,Sum=g.Sum(o=>o.Total)}` just works, and generates `select c.Name as Category,SUM(Total) from Orders o INNER JOIN Categories c on o.CategoryId=c.ID GROUP BY c.Name`.  Right now it's worse than using raw SQL. Your LINQ query should look like your SQL query anyway, provided you used JOINs in SQL as well. No casts, no T2 fields in the `group` clause.

Comment: Thank you all. Updated the query to facilitate interpretation

Comment: So you aren't using LINQ and EF Core. You used the repository *anti*pattern to load everything in memory and now try to emulate SQL grouping. Even so there's no need for the casts. It's the *SQL* query that needs cleaning up though. If you use JOINs *there*, you'll get a query that can be roughly translated to LINQ.

Comment: I'm using LINQ e EF Core, only when I run var results = "ToList" it loads into memory.

Comment: Not in the code you posted. And if you use `_db.T1.ToList()` in `GetAll()` you're misusing it. It's EF Core's job to generate the queries. And the entire reason of using queries is so you *don't* have to load three 1K tables in memory without indexing, perform 1M *1K^3) comparisons just to get a few result rows. Because that's what your code will do if it works. A `List<T>` has no indexes and a client's RAM and CPU are far, far weaker than any server. The server can easily find just the relevant rows using the indexes that cover the keys and efficiently group the necessary values and columns

Comment: Hi @Panagiotis Kanavos.  I don't use it, the getAll() repository corresponds to ({Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1[App.Models.T1Model]}), in reality the repositories are interfaces of the "Abp framework" (https://docs.abp .io/en/abp/4.4/Repositories). But the problem is in the conversion, that is, in reproducing the query with entity framework.

Comment: Thank you all. Updated the query to facilitator interpretation. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to convert the query, with entity framework?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
var query = 
    (from xT1 in T1
     join xT3 in T3 on new { k1 = (long)xT1.O_KEY } equals new { k1 = (long)xT3.O_KEY }
     join xT2 in T2 on new { k1 = (long)xT1.M_KEY } equals new { k1 = (long)T2.M_KEY}
     select new { xT1, xT2, xT3 } into x
     group x by new { x.xT3.COD1 , x.xT1.COD2} into G
     select new ResultDTO
     {
      COD1 = G.Key.COD1,
      COD2 = G.Key.COD2,
      R1 = G.Count(),
      R2 = Convert.ToDecimal(G.Sum(x => (decimal)x.X2) / T2.Sum(x => (decimal)x.X2)),
    });
```